# creating new variable that takes into account prior information from the earlier records

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyr

I have data as follows and I want to create new variable that takes into account the preceding information in the prior period. For example,

```
moviewatched<- c('Comedy', 'Horror', 'Comedy', 'Horror', 'Drama', 'Comedy', 'Drama')
name<- c('john', 'john', 'john', 'john', 'john','kate','kate')
time<- c('1-2018', '1-2018', '1-2018', '2-2018', '2-2018','1-2018' ,'2-2018')


df<- data.frame(moviewatched, name, time)
```

Now I need to create a variable that will tell what are the new type of genre movies he/she watched in that month. For example, in the above case, John watched 2 genre types in the first month of 2018 and watched 1 new additional type in second month(as he has already watched comedy and horror in the first month).Is there any way I can create a running count of the new types that person started watching? I want to create a variable called movietypewatched that contains total of the all genre types that person watched till that month.  The output expected is as follows:

```
     name time   movietypewatched 
     john 1-2018       2
     john 2-2018       3
     kate 1-2018       1
     kate 2-2018       2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a table of first dates watched; count by month; and take the cumulative sum:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

# fix bad date
df[, d := as.IDate(paste(time, "01", sep="-"), "%m-%Y-%d")]

# identify month first watched
fw = df[, .(d = min(d)), by=.(name, moviewatched)]

# count new movies per month
nm = fw[, .N, keyby=.(name, d)]

# take cumulative count
nm[, cN := cumsum(N), by=name]

   name          d N cN
1: john 2018-01-01 2  2
2: john 2018-02-01 1  3
3: kate 2018-01-01 1  1
4: kate 2018-02-01 1  2
```

You need to convert the date; otherwise the min() will be incorrect and/or broken.

There are two aggregation steps here, but the code should be fast thanks to optimization in data.table (see `?GForce`).

Answer (score 3):

A solution using `dplyr`. We can remove duplicated rows based on `moviewatched` and `name`, count unique `moviewatched`, and then use `cumsum` to calcualte the running total. `df2` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  distinct(moviewatched, name, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(name, time) %>%
  summarise(movietypewatched = n_distinct(moviewatched)) %>%
  mutate(movietypewatched = cumsum(movietypewatched)) %>%
  ungroup()
df2
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   name  time   movietypewatched
#   <fct> <fct>             <int>
# 1 john  1-2018                2
# 2 john  2-2018                3
# 3 kate  1-2018                1
# 4 kate  2-2018                2
```

And here is a `data.table` solution following the same logic.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
df2 <- df[!duplicated(df[, .(moviewatched, name)])][
  , .(movietypewatched = uniqueN(moviewatched)), by = .(name, time)][
    , movietypewatched := cumsum(movietypewatched), by = name]
df2[]
#    name   time movietypewatched
# 1: john 1-2018                2
# 2: john 2-2018                3
# 3: kate 1-2018                1
# 4: kate 2-2018                2
```

Comment: wow. I don't get how `n_distinct` see across the grouping.. Is it because of `summarise` ?

Comment: And what would be the equivalent in `data.table`? I am unable to do that, although I knew it was the way. for example `df[,uniqueN(moviewatched),by = .(time,name)]` won't work because `uniqueN` is within the grouping.

Comment: @denis I think `distinct` and `group_by` before the `summarise` function are important.

Comment: This is an interesting approach. It's important that `distinct` with `.keep_all = TRUE` keeps the first of multiple observations, which is what you want here, provided `time` is sorted. Probably safest to call `arrange` beforehand to ensure correct order.

Comment: @denis Please see my update as a `data.table` solution.

Comment: @alistaire Thanks. I agree that it is important to make sure the order is correct.

Comment: @www Bravo for the `data.table` solution. I didn't know `duplicated` either. I ll delete my crappy answer. Thanks again

Comment: Fyi, the following syntax is supported: duplicated(DT, by=c("col1", "col2")), though in this case you should do unique(DT, by=c("col1", "col2")), I guess.

Comment: @Frank Good to know `duplicated(DT, by=c("col1", "col2"))`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First convert the time data to a class to establish order, e.g. with `lubridate::myd` with `truncated = 1`. From here, set the arrangement of rows to ensure they're in order, then, grouped by `name`, use `purrr::accumulate` to generate a list of unique values seen so far in `moviewatched`, called upon which `lengths` will return the number of movies seen to that point. Aggregate by month with `max` to get the total cumulative types for each month.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data_frame(
    moviewatched =  c('Comedy', 'Horror', 'Comedy', 'Horror', 'Drama', 'Comedy', 'Drama'),
    name =  c('john', 'john', 'john', 'john', 'john','kate','kate'),
    time =  lubridate::myd(c('1-2018', '1-2018', '1-2018', '2-2018', '2-2018','1-2018' ,'2-2018'), truncated = 1)
)

df %>% 
    group_by(name) %>% 
    arrange(name, time) %>%
    mutate(n_types = lengths(accumulate(moviewatched, ~unique(c(...))))) %>% 
    group_by(name, time) %>% 
    summarise(n_types = max(n_types))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Groups:   name [2]
#>   name  time       n_types
#>   <chr> <date>       <dbl>
#> 1 john  2018-01-01       2
#> 2 john  2018-02-01       3
#> 3 kate  2018-01-01       1
#> 4 kate  2018-02-01       2
```

Comment: How can I get the actual count of the new movie watched? for example, 2,1, 1,1 showing only the new movie types that he/she watched, thanks so much.

Comment: maybe `df %>% 
    group_by(name) %>% 
    arrange(name, time) %>%
    mutate(new = c(1, diff(lengths(accumulate(moviewatched, ~unique(c(...))))))) %>% 
    group_by(name, time) %>% 
    summarise(types = sum(new))`

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
df <- unique(df) 
setDT(df)[, movietypewatched := 1:.N, by = c("moviewatched", "name")] 
df <- df[!(movietypewatched == 2), ]
df[, movietypewatched := .N, by = c("name", "time")][, moviewatched := NULL]
df <- unique(df)
df[, movietypewatched := cumsum(movietypewatched), by = name]

   name   time movietypewatched
1: john 1-2018                2
2: john 2-2018                3
3: kate 1-2018                1
4: kate 2-2018                2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can make intermediate steps if you'd like to get the unique values in `genre_all` and the count in `genre_count`.

Note that:

- You need to arrange the dataframe by `name, date` to accumulate values.
- You can use `lag()` to get the previous value. Since the first entry for each `name` has no previous value, it will give `NA`.
- You will need to remove the NAs when you count the unique genres using `n_distinct()`.

>

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

moviewatched <- c('Comedy', 'Horror', 'Comedy', 'Horror', 'Drama', 'Comedy', 'Drama')
name <- c('john', 'john', 'john', 'john','kate','kate', 'john')
time <- c( '1-2018', '1-2018', '2-2018', '2-2018','1-2018' ,'2-2018','1-2018')

df <- data.frame(moviewatched, name, time)


df_final <- df %>% 
  arrange(name, time) %>% 
  group_by(name, time) %>%
  nest(.key= 'genre') %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(genre_all = map2(genre, lag(genre), rbind) %>% map(unique)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(genre_count = map_int(genre_all, ~ lift(n_distinct)(.x, na.rm =TRUE)))
```

Result:

```
> df_final
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  name  time   genre            genre_all        genre_count
  <fct> <fct>  <list>           <list>                 <int>
1 john  1-2018 <tibble [3 x 1]> <tibble [3 x 1]>           2
2 john  2-2018 <tibble [2 x 1]> <tibble [3 x 1]>           3
3 kate  1-2018 <tibble [1 x 1]> <tibble [2 x 1]>           1
4 kate  2-2018 <tibble [1 x 1]> <tibble [2 x 1]>           2
```